Optimize execution time of .NET MAUI bobile app test suite using Xamarin.UITest and NUnit?
Executing test cases for .NET MAUI mobile applications takes much time using Xamarin.UITest and NUnit. The major component of the time consumption is the duration between the app's termination and relaunch between each unit test case.
The test cases involve the below operations

Performing gestures on the app's UI such as IApp.Tap,
IApp.DragCoordinates.
For non-UI operations, executing backdoor operations on the app
using the IApp.Invoke method.
Capturing the screen and comparing it with the expected
screenshot. Assert fail or pass based on whether there is
a difference.

For thousands of test cases in each platform (Android and iOS), it takes more than a day for all the test cases to be executed. Is there any way to optimize the test suite execution time for .NET MAUI apps, so that thousands of test cases can be executed in a few hours?
